# Show content from another controller in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem: I want to show images inside the post views. I have the following controllers:

```
# posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:titulo, :slug, :texto, :imagem)
    end

end
```

and

```
# imgs_controller.rb
class ImgsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_img, only: [:show]

  # GET /imgs
  # GET /imgs.json
  def index
    @imgs = Img.all
  end

  # GET /imgs/1
  # GET /imgs/1.json
  def show
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_img
      @img = Img.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def img_params
      params.require(:img).permit(:imagem, :nome, :descricao, :to_slide)
    end
end
```

How can I call the methods 'index' and/or 'show' of **ImgsController** inside the **views/posts/index.html.erb**? Is there a way?

Comment: The best starting point is Rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

If you want to render your images within your post views, you should make those resources available within your posts_controller.

I assume you have an association somewhat like

```
class Post
  has_many :images
end
```

So you could do something like:

```
# posts/index.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <p><%= post.name %></p>
  <% @post.images.each do |img|
    <p><%= img.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can render any template file:

```
render "posts/show" # or index
```

[Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

I assume that you have logic that works with both or you controller variables.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers helped me to see the solution.
I read the guide as Benjamin Sinclair said.

All I needed to do was put

```
@imgs = Img.all
```

inside the method 'index' of **PostsController**.

So, I called **@imgs** in views/posts/index.html.erb

Simple!

Thanks!